# Is it common/acceptable to use "the feeling of vulnerabilities"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

Instead of saying *I don't like to feel vulnerable*, are the following acceptable too?

- I don't like the feeling of vulnerabilities.
- The feeling of vulnerabilities crippled me.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, "I don't like feeling vulnerable."

Or,

"I was crippled by feelings of vulnerability" (this is an example of where passive voice is appropriate to emphasize that the speaker is being acted upon by something else)

Answer (score 0):

You should say "the feeling of vulnerability", because vulnerability is an uncountable noun.
See [Results found on Google Book](https://books.google.com/books?id=i3HaAAAAMAAJ&q=%22the%20feeling%20of%20vulnerability%22&dq=%22the%20feeling%20of%20vulnerability%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi99bybv4vjAhUHzIsBHZcuCGYQ6AEIKDAA)

Comment: *Vulnerability* definitely can be a countable noun. *I don't let **my vulnerabilities** get the better of me*. *She only has* ***two vulnerabilities.*** You need to change or expand your answer to explain why it's singular in this case.